# How do I control how SQLite3 imports a CSV file?

Tags: csv, import, sqlite

Is there any way to control table creation when importing a .csv file in SQLite3?

My sample .csv file has 7 columns, with the first row containing column names, followed by 10 rows of "data". However, the resultant table is not as expected.

First, the column headings are created as quoted text, therefore to `SELECT` any of the imported columns requires the column names to be entered with single quotes to avoid a "no such column" error (e.g. `SELECT TopTemp FROM Readings;` gives `Error: no such column: TopTemp` but `SELECT 'TopTemp' FROM Readings;` is OK.) The .csv file does not have quoted strings.

Second, all data is entered as `TEXT`. So although the 'data' imported is mostly columns of real (floating point) numbers it is not possible to use any aggregate functions.  Is there any way to control the column data type on import?

Comment: Create the table ahead of time with the column names and types you want, delete the header line from the csv file, and then import. (Or import into a scratch table, then `INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM scratch_table` and drop the scratch one)

Comment: Oh, and it's double quotes for identifiers. Are there spaces in the header line at the beginning or end of fields? That's the usual reason for what you're seeing. They get included in the generated column names.

Comment: Edited for readability by breaking the question into paragraphs and removing things that did not seem relevant.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, predefining the column names and types is the best way forward. However, stripping any whitespace from the header row does create the column names OK without the need for quotes.